# Create Method that has dynamic number of parametr

Tags: c#

Is possible to create method with dynamic number of parameter in C#?

For example

```
Public void sum(dynamic arguments//like JavaScript)
{
   //loop at run-time  on arguments and sum
}
```

> Can I use Dynamic Object?

Comment: are you looking for `params`? bla(params int[] variableInts)

Comment: How about this: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=method+with+dynamic+number+of+parameter+c%23

Comment: It would really have helped if you'd posted an example of how you want to *call* the method.

Comment: Are you looking for variable number of arguments or the `dynamic` type as parameter? and could you update your question accordingly, kinda vague atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`params` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to achieve a variable number of arguments.

> The params keyword lets you specify a method parameter that takes a
>   variable number of arguments. You can send a comma-separated list of
>   arguments of the type specified in the parameter declaration, or an
>   array of arguments of the specified type. You also can send no
>   arguments.

For example: `public void Sum( params int[] args ){ }`

> Can I use Dynamic Object?

Yes, but possibly not in the way you are thinking.

```
// example 1 - single parameter of type dynamic
private static void Sum( dynamic args ) { }

// will not compile; Sum() expects a single parameter whose type is not
// known until runtime
Sum( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );

// example 2 - variable number of dynamically typed arguments
private static void Sum( params dynamic[] args ) { }

// will compile
Sum( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
```

So you could have a method such as:

```
public static dynamic Sum( params dynamic[] args ) {

    dynamic sum = 0;

    foreach( var arg in args ){
        sum += arg;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

And call it: `Sum( 1, 2, 3, 4.5, 5 )`. The DLR is smart enough to infer the correct type from the arguments, and the returned value will be `System.Double`. **However** (at least in the case of a `Sum()` method), giving up explicit control over type specification and losing type safety seems like a bad idea.

I'm assuming you have a reason for not using [Enumerable.Sum()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx)

Comment: `dynamic` is used when you want to wait until runtime to resolve the type; A sum method implies that you *do* know the type.

Comment: `private static void Sum( params dynamic[] args )` will compile, if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can take a look here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w5zay9db(v=vs.80).aspx

(the `params` keyword)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an example unit test clarifies things slightly:

```
    [Test]
    public void SumDynamics()
    {
        // note that we can specify as many ints as we like
        Assert.AreEqual(8, Sum(3, 5)); // test passes
        Assert.AreEqual(4, Sum(1, 1 , 1, 1)); // test passes
        Assert.AreEqual(3, Sum(3)); // test passes
    }

    // Meaningless example but it's purpose is only to show that you can use dynamic 
    // as a parameter, and that you also can combine it with the params type.
    public static dynamic Sum(params dynamic[] ints)
    {
        return ints.Sum(i => i);
    }
```

Be aware when using dynamics, you are telling your compiler to back off, so you will get your exceptions at run-time.

```
    [Test, ExpectedException(typeof(RuntimeBinderException))]
    public void AssignDynamicIntAndStoreAsString()
    {
        dynamic i = 5;
        string astring = i; // this will compile, but will throw a runtime exception
    }
```

---

Read more about [dynamics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx).

Read more about [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)